# Trigger click on page load in wordpress

Tags: javascript, triggers, onclick, wordpress-theming

I am using this code for a custom form i made in wordpress.

```
document.querySelector('.startLINK a').onclick = function() {
    let wrpms = document.querySelector('.firstscren');
    let formslider = document.querySelector('.form-slider');
    wrpms.setAttribute('style','display:none');
    formslider.setAttribute('style','display:flex');
};
```

How do I make the link (.startLINK a) automatically trigger on page load in wordpress?